# jQuery trim for required field

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

I have a textbox for user to enter full name.

Now on keyup, I call the following code (part of my changeAction call);

```
target.value = $.trim(target.value);
```

So the code trims the value entered by the user.

Also since this is a required field, I use it to enable Submit button.

Now the issue is, because of the above code, if the user enters any space (say while typing "Mike Dennis") , he is not allowed to (after Mike) since the trim() is called ?

How do I fix this while ensuring that the other logic works (specifically button enabling)?
I cannot use "blur" event here..

Comment: run this code on losing focus rather than on keyup

Comment: $('#elementofInterest').on('blur', function (e) {e.target.value = $.trim(e.target.value);})

Comment: I know that is an option...but unfortunately my requirement is that I need to run on keyup..i.e as the user types...

Comment: ok so all you have to do is not allow the user to enter **space only**. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not to allow user to enter the spaces only and trim after the user finished the typing

Here's the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v8qj2suc/2/

The HTML

`<input type="text" id="elementOFInterest" />`

The Javascript

`$("#elementOFInterest").on('keyup', function (e){
    var target = e.target;
    if($.trim(target.value) == "" ){
        target.value = "";
    }
});
$("#elementOFInterest").on('blur', function (e){
    var target = e.target;
    target.value = $.trim(target.value);
});`